# Read data off Apple NGFF M2

Tags: linux, mac, usb, scsi, nvme

I have one of those propietary NGFF M2 SSDs found in older Macbooks. I bought a converter which is supposed to convert it to a standard NVMe. When I plug it in my Linux box only sees it as a SCSI device. It doesn't show in `lsblk` and I can't `dd` anything in and out of it.

This is `dmesg` after I plug it in:

```
[13986.979903] usb 4-1.2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[13987.002963] usb 4-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0562
[13987.002967] usb 4-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[13987.002970] usb 4-1.2: Product: External
[13987.002972] usb 4-1.2: Manufacturer: JMicron
[13987.002975] usb 4-1.2: SerialNumber: DD56419883893
[13987.010561] scsi host4: uas
[13987.011328] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     JMicron  Tech             0204 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[13987.012187] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[13995.821905] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Unit Not Ready
[13995.821910] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[13995.821920] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[13995.826240] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[13995.826245] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[13995.826252] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[13995.832231] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[13995.832235] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[13995.832241] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[13995.832976] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[13995.832977] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] 0-byte physical blocks
[13995.837231] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
// ************
// THESE ARE IN RED
[13995.839200] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Asking for cache data failed
[13995.839205] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
// ************
[13995.845204] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (0 bytes)
[13995.845803] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Unit Not Ready
[13995.845808] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[13995.845814] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[13995.850161] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[13995.850164] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[13995.850167] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[13995.853614] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[13995.853618] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[13995.853623] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[13995.853696] sd 4:0:0:0: tag#0 data cmplt err -75 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[13995.853700] sd 4:0:0:0: tag#0 CDB: Inquiry 12 01 00 00 40 00
[14027.686957] sd 4:0:0:0: tag#1 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 2 inflight: CMD 
[14027.686964] sd 4:0:0:0: tag#1 CDB: Test Unit Ready 00 00 00 00 00 00
[14027.686971] sd 4:0:0:0: tag#0 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[14027.686975] sd 4:0:0:0: tag#0 CDB: Inquiry 12 01 00 00 40 00
[14027.714945] scsi host4: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[14027.801200] usb 4-1.2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[14027.827408] scsi host4: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
[14027.847729] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
```

This is what I got going on:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07V3L1TDT/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07V3L1TDT)

And that ^ is plugged into an NVMe to USB converter:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07JKWHFRC/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JKWHFRC)

Haha, looks very rigged. No wonder it doesn't work! But I did try the NGFF to NVMe converter directly into a PCIe NVMe card and I'm getting a similar result:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07JKH5VTL/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JKH5VTL)

UPDATE:

I tried another Mac NGFF SSD and a different brand NGFF to NVMe converter and I'm getting the same exact dmesg

Comment: But does the SSD work? This output makes me think it may be dead.

Comment: @MichaelHampton it PROBABLY works... I have a duplicate SSD that I tried and it does the same thing. I thought maybe it was the Mac NGFF to NVMe but I put the NGFF SSD in a PCI card converter and I got the same exact result.

Comment: Those old Macs had SATA SSDs, not NVMe. (Though you could install NVMe SSDs in them after a firmware update.) That's probably where things are going wrong here. Plug the M.2 adapter directly into the computer, or use a different adapter.